# nodemon can not find module debug

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, nodemon

I am trying to write a basic MEAN stack application using the express generator command. I am able to run `npm start` and was able to run my app. However, when I run `nodemon` I am getting the following error.

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'debug'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/nodemon/lib/nodemon.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I have checked that the `node_modules` folder does contain the `debug` module. I am not able to see where I am going wrong. Can you please help?

Comment: Personally I think supervisor or pm2 is better choice than nodemon

Comment: I have tried pm2 and it is working, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that problem many times with nodemon, delete all node modules, run `npm i` again then try reloading your server.

Comment: I have tried this many time but it is not working. Do you know of any other workaround? Or can you point me to a probable cause.